# moving image from right to left - animation not working

Tags: html, css

I want to move an image from right to left, the image should enters from the right side of the screen and exits from left side of the screen, for that I have written this css animation code but it is not working please help.

**.CSS file**

```
.imageAnimation { 
    position: 100% 0px;
    -webkit-animation: moveToLeft 10s linear infinite;
    animation: moveToLeft 10s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToLeft {
    from {position: 100% 0px;}
    to {position: 0% 0px;}
}

@keyframes moveToLeft {
    from {position: 100% 0px;}
    to {position: 0% 0px;}
}
```

**.HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animation.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img class="imageAnimation" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:100%;" src="enemy.png" width="300" height="100"/>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you have a codepen or jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  animation: moveImage 3s linear infinite;
  left: -350px;
}

@keyframes moveImage {
    100% {
      transform: translateX(calc(100vw + 350px));
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

**350px** in `translateX(calc(100vw + 350px));` is `width` of image so image will go to end of **window** + `width` of image. So you will have to change that for width of your image, same for `left: -350px`.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually really close...just using [`position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#position-property) incorrectly. Use `top` and `left` instead.

```
.imageAnimation { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: moveToLeft 10s linear infinite;
    animation: moveToLeft 10s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToLeft {
    from {left: 100%;}
    to {left: 0%;}
}

@keyframes moveToLeft {
    from {left: 100%;}
    to {left: 0%;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer uses `calc` and percentages so the box will start outside of the right side of the screen, across the view port area and out of the left side of the screen. You can [read about calc browser support here](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc). Heres the code:

```
.wrap {
  background: pink;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
  animation-name: moveToLeft;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  background-color: red;
  height:100px;
  left:calc(0% - 100px);
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
}
@keyframes moveToLeft {
    0% {left:calc(100% + 100px);}
    100% {left:calc(0% - 100px);}
}

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I use a parent container with an `overflow: hidden` so the scroll bar will not show when the box is out of the frame. Also the `100px` you see in the `calc` will need to be the same width as your element. Here is a [js.fiddle with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/kamnndz5/3/). Hope that helps.